# How should I be using my Projection to draw points in the map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw some circles on the map based on longitude and latitude, However, I think there is something wrong with my projection because it does not draw my anything.

I got the following,

I have a global variable

var projection = d3.geoMercator()

then, I define the projection:

```
  projection.scale(1).translate([0, 0]);
      var b = path.bounds(data);
      var s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / mwidth, (b[1][1] -
              b[0][1]) / mheight);
      var t = [(mwidth - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (mheight - s *
              (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2+50];
      projection.scale(s).translate(t);
```

And this is the way I am trying to Implement my circles,

```
 // Hospital points
     svg.selectAll('.hospital-circle')
        .data(hospitals)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'boundary')
        .attr('r', 5)
        .attr('cx', function(d) {
              var hospitalCoords = projection.scale(s).translate(t)([d.lon, d.lat])
              console.log(d)
              console.log(hospitalCoords);
              return hospitalCoords[0]
        })
        .attr('cy', function(d) {
              var hospitalCoords = projection.scale(s).translate(t)([d.lon, d.lat])
              console.log(d)
              console.log(hospitalCoords)
              return hospitalCoords[1]
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's going wrong for certain, since we can't see your data and we don't know how it fits with your projection. It looks to me like you're calling `projection` correctly but it probably doesn't mesh with your region properly. You should probably use `projection.fitSize`, rather than trying to do that manually. I've attached a complete, working code snippet to illustrate

```js
let w = 500;
let h = 300;
let div = d3.select('#container');
let svg = div.append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);
let map = svg.append('g');

let largest_cities = d3.csvParse(`name,population,lat,lon
New York City,8550405,40.6642738,-73.9385004
Los Angeles,3971883,34.0193936,-118.4108248
Chicago,2720546,41.8375511,-87.6818441
Houston,2296224,29.7804724,-95.3863425
Phoenix,1563025,33.5721625,-112.0879662
Philadelphia,1567442,40.0093755,-75.1333459
San Antonio,1469845,29.4724026,-98.5251419
San Diego,1394928,32.8152995,-117.134993
Dallas,1300092,32.794176,-96.7655033
San Jose,1026908,37.2968672,-121.8193058
Austin,931830,30.3071816,-97.7559964
Jacksonville,868031,30.3370193,-81.6613021
San Francisco,864816,37.759881,-122.437392
Columbus,850106,39.9847989,-82.9850438
Fort Worth,833319,32.7795423,-97.3463354
Indianapolis,858325,39.7779954,-86.1458378
Charlotte,827097,35.2087069,-80.8307389
Seattle,684451,47.6204993,-122.3508761
Denver,682545,39.7618487,-104.8806251
Washington,672228,38.9041485,-77.0170942
`, d3.autoType);
let max_pop = d3.max(largest_cities.map((c) => c.population));
  

fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scdoshi/us-geojson/master/geojson/nation/US.geojson').then(async function(response) {
  let us = await response.json();
  let projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa().fitSize([w, h], us);
  let path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
  map
    .append('path')
    .attr("d", path(us))
    .attr("fill", "lightgray")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1);
  largest_cities.forEach(function (c) {
    let xy = projection([c.lon, c.lat]);
    c.x = xy[0];
    c.y = xy[1];
  });
  map
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(largest_cities)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("cx", (c) => c.x)
    .attr("cy", (c) => c.y)
    .attr("r", (c) => 5 * (c.population / max_pop) ** 0.3)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```